# Possible design bug: Medal colors

Tags: bug, design

I had a tough time with the image uploader (bad overlay, then when i deleted the overlay and tried to upload it wouldn't go?), but when you get out of the black bar up top and out of the "gold on the left, silver in the middle, bronze on the right" context, the colors look swapped:

http://cl.ly/image/2Q2g1e1d3n2j

Color is subjective, it might be my monitor, etc. But to me, the bronze looks gold and the gold looks bronze.

I'd also suggest that the different shapes make the medals feel like different sizes as well; the silver badge looks a lot bigger than the bronze one. But that's a smaller nit to pick.

Appreciate you guys, thanks!

Comment: color is not subjective, visually impaired users most certainly do not see what you expect them to (color blind users) or see anything at all (blind users).

Answer (score 2):

Seconded: my suggestion would be; in addition to get the gold-bronze the right way around;

1. to fill them instead of outline
2. and go from simple shape to complex shape: bronze circle, silver
   triangle, gold diamond

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion. I should use filled instead of outlined for better readability.

Comment: It would be readability helpful. And you could of course switch the complex-to-simple the other way around. Gold circle, silver triangle, bronze diamond

Answer (score 1):

Also the contrast is too damn low on light background like on post names. The alternative order for me is

1. bronze triangle
2. silver diamond
3. gold circle